# pass environment variable to node.js process in CircleCI

Tags: circleci

I am getting environment variables in CircleCI `config.yml` by using CircleCI context (Project Settings -> Environment Variables.

I am not able to pass them to node.js process `process.env.SERVER_API`. They are `undefined`.

I tried to them to pass it in `config.yml`:

```
docker:
      - image: circleci/node:14.9.0
        environment:
          SERVER_API: $SERVER_API
```

It doesn't work and I don't know how to pass them.

**config.yml**

```
version: 2.1
executors:
  node-executor:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:14.9.0
        environment:
          SERVER_API: $SERVER_API
commands:
  gatsby-build:
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - yarn-cache-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: yarn install
      - save_cache:
          key: yarn-cache-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
      - run:
          name: Gatsby Build
          command: yarn build
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - release:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
jobs:
  release:
    executor: node-executor
    working_directory: ~/tau-guide-website
    steps:
      - gatsby-build
      - run:
          name: Deploy
          command: |
            #upload all the code to machine
            scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ~/tau-guide-website/public $PROJECT_FOLDER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables present during the Circle CI build are not passed to the deployed code, unless explicitly done.
For my project I'm using available Circle CI env variable for the pipeline, but export them to .env file to include them in the final package. For the current code, I would:

Remove this from image:

`environment: SERVER_API: $SERVER_API`

Add additional code to your build step:

```
      - run:
          name: Gatsby Build
          command: |
            touch .env.production
            echo "SERVER_API=$SERVER_API" > .env.production
            yarn build
```

In case .env is not used at all, consider reading about [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). You'll need to bring in dotenv as a dependancy and declare it in your files like so:

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

For our use case .env contains DB credentials and secrets as well, but is in `.gitignore` and generated during builds.

Comment: If I add `echo "SERVER_IP=$SERVER_IP" >> $PROJECT_FOLDER/.env`, I get error message `/bin/bash: line 1: *********************************************************/.env: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Matt
There was a slight mistake in the script, I have updated it.
For first export of variable we need to use overwrite operator ">" and not the append operator ">>".

Comment: I tried to use `>` operator and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Matt the issue is related to this: https://superuser.com/q/867363 . I have added a script to solve the issue.

Comment: I tried this `eval "echo \"SERVER_IP=$SERVER_IP\" > $PROJECT_FOLDER/.env"` and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Matt wow that's a bummer. I have simplified the main script that should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I don't think this will work. `$PROJECT_FOLDER` is path on remote AWS machine where I want to copy files.

Comment: @Matt, yeah, that was the issue, thanks for pointing out. We should go to `~/tau-guide-website/public`. Script updated.

Comment: I tried it out and it passed successfully, but the `SERVER_API` is `undefined`. At first, I tried `cd ~/tau-guide-website/public`, then I tried `cd ~/tau-guide-website` and it didn't help. Thanks for trying to help. Just to give you more context, this is the config [file](https://github.com/TauGuide/tau-guide-website/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml) and the project is in GatsbyJS. For example [here](https://github.com/TauGuide/tau-guide-website/blob/master/src/services/distributionService.js#L5) you can see where `SERVER_API` is `undefined` after building the project.

Comment: I can't access these files. With Gatsby.JS there are .env.development, .env.production or .env files linked to other environments. Hence the simple .env file is being ignored.

We can update the file name for .env so it is picked up by the project.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that project is not public. Yes, it is a good point that Gatsby uses `.env.production` for building process. I [tried](https://imgur.com/a/tllqBhd) to use `.env.production` instead of `.env`, but `SERVER_API` is still `undefined`. Do you have any idea what I can try next?

Comment: @Matt
I've just found a typo in the script and corrected it. We need to pass $SERVER_API to the .env.production and not $SERVER_IP. Hopefully it will be available now.

Comment: I added [screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/WuqPZJQ), where you can see what I tried, but `SERVER_API` is still `undefined`.

Comment: @Matt,
Interesting. Where is the $SERVER_API coming from? Are you sure it's available during the pipeline?
We can confirm by `echo $SERVER_API`, once confirmed we will look into GatsbyJS project.

Comment: I set up `SERVER_API` as environmental variable in CircleCI project [settings](https://imgur.com/a/fciwpjz) and this variable is used in Gatsby project like [this](https://imgur.com/a/pOTi1on). I attached some screenshots from CircleCI [log](https://imgur.com/a/Dg3f0hW).

Comment: @Matt, were you using .env.production before? if not, have you added the dotenv dependency in your code?

You'll need to bring in dotenv as a dependancy and declare it in your files like so :

require('dotenv').config({
  
path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,

})

Comment: Yes, when I build project on my local machine instead of CircleCI, everything is working fine and `SERVER_API` value is set from `.env.production` file.

Comment: @Matt, .env.production file should be available before we build the project!

So, you need to generate the .env.production file in Gatsby Build step. I think we are near. (Script updated)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles into this problem in the future and is in a monorepo setup, remember to put the path to the package you are using!

I've literally spent a week on and off on getting this working and the answer was this simple.

```
# Wrong
env > .env
# Correct
env > path/to/package/.env
```

If you don't give the path to the package you will end up placing the `.env` at the root of the monorepo where it is out of reach of the package that needs it.